# three.js orbitcontrols.js wiht custom handleTouchMoveRotate()

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, quaternions

im trying to get touch controls from https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls to rotate over a camera axis with quaternions.
this gives no errors, it is not changing the camera rotation at all.
here is my version of handletouchmoverotate from orbit controls:

```js
function handleTouchMoveRotate( event ) {

  if ( pointers.length == 1 ) {
    rotateEnd.set( event.pageX, event.pageY );
  } 
  else {
    const position = getSecondPointerPosition( event );
    const x = 0.5 * ( event.pageX + position.x );
    const y = 0.5 * ( event.pageY + position.y );
    rotateEnd.set( x, y );
  }

  rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );
  const element = scope.domElement;
  const _Q = new Quaternion();
  const _A = new Vector3();
  const _R = new Quaternion();

  _R.copy(object.quaternion);  // object is camera
  _A.set(0, -1, 0).normalize();
  _Q.setFromAxisAngle(_A, 9111.001 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x);  // tried everything from 0.001 to 9000
  _R.multiply(_Q);
  object.quaternion.copy(_R);

  rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

}
```

Edit: trackball controls dose what I want, I'm not sure why what I wrote did not work but I will use trackball controls